# Moving files to the respectful folders based on their extensions

Tags: python, shutil

I need to move the files with the extensions, which are not listed in dict, to 'Unknown_folder'. It works, however when I add 'else:', all files (even with the extensions listed in the dict) will be moved to 'Unknown_folder). Please help to sort it out.

```py
my_dict = {f'{path}/images': ['JPEG', 'PNG', 'JPG', 'SVG'], f'{path}/video': ['AVI', 'MP4', 'MOV', 'MKV'], f'{path}/documents': ['DOC', 'DOCX', 'TXT', 'PDF', 'XLSX', 'PPTX'], f'{path}/audio': ['MP3', 'OGG', 'WAV', 'AMR']}

for destination, extension in my_dict.items():
    for ext in extension:
        for obj in os.listdir(path):
            if not os.path.isdir(obj):
                if obj.endswith(f'.{ext.lower()}'):
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(path,obj), os.path.join(destination,obj))
                else:
                    shutil.move(os.path.join(path,obj), os.path.join(f'{path}/Unknown_extensions',obj))
```

Comment: You are looping on extensions then the actual list of names. You should reverse the order and take each item and compare its extension to the valid list. Right now if your first extension is .arc  but your files are all .txt  you will assign everything to unknown because you look at arc files before txt files